# Two classes constructor calling each other

Tags: php

I have two classes that are initiiating objects of both in their constructors. see example below

```
class A
{
function __construct()
{
   $this->b=new B();
}
}

class B
{
function __construct()
{
$this->a=new A()
}
```

Is there any solution for this in spite of not doing this :)

Comment: Should these objects refer to each other? I.e., should `$this->b->a === $this`?

Comment: Yes. there is a way. Just don't do it. It's infinite recursion. `//hint`: explain what do you want from it

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 2):

That's hard to answer as this is so abstract, but if I understand well, I would tend to do this :

```
class A {
    function __construct() {
        $this->b = new B($this);
    }
}

class B {
    function __construct(A $a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}
```

I suppose here that B is a component of A. If it's not the case, you probably have a problem with your design.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion Loop 3000 ->

```
class A
{
    private $b;

    function __construct()
    {
         $this->b=new B();
    }
}

class B
{
    private $a;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->a=new A()
    }
}
```

Don't know what you wanna achieve with this, though.